# web crawler in python (multiple website )

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

I used `requests` and `bs4`. In the circle, I found that it's only the last 'soup' is right when i get every 'soup'.the other 'soup' is different with HTML source. Please help me. Thanks.

```
for eachLine in files:
    addr = 'http://neuromorpho.org/neuron_info.jsp?neuron_name='+eachLine
    print addr
    st = []
    st1 = []
    r2 = requests.get(addr)
    soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r2.text,"lxml")
    print soup2
```

Answer (score 0):

The request object has content parameter which has all content of the site and you can parse it using BS4

```
for eachLine in files:
    addr = 'http://neuromorpho.org/neuron_info.jsp?neuron_name='+eachLine
    r2 = requests.get(addr)
    content = r2.content
    soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content)
    print soup2
```